# How algebra differs in complex plane and cartesian plane?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

I noticed the difference first when I tried to convert the complex form of the equation of circle in cartesian form, this is how I approached-

$$\tag{1}|z-a|=r \qquad (\text{here},z= x+iy)  $$

I thought, $iy$ corresponds to $Y$-axis in the Cartesian plane,
and, my converted equation was this-
$$\tag{2}
                        |x+y-a|=r
$$
this was simple, then I went to proof

1)
$$
                                         |z-a|=r
$$
$$
                                        (z-a)^2= r^2                                 
$$
$$
                                       z^2-2za+a^2=r^2 
$$
Another form of it is- zz¯−z0¯z−z0z¯+(|z0|2−R2)=0, but I did not approach to that,
Now the prof of-

2. 

$$      
                              |x+y|=r
$$
$$
                            x^2+2xy+y^2=r^2
$$

this looks very similar to 1. But, it does not give a circle, when I plot it. The 2xy seems to get in my way of circle.

another thing that I learned is-
iy.i= -y
it is a 90-degree tilt of y

but in the cartesian plane, you have to multiply -1.

```
                         y.(-1)=y
```

I lack information in this field, I want to know how the cartesian plane is different from the complex plane? what distinguishes them?
how to make a connection with the complex geometry and cartesian geometry?

Comment: You have been around for months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: (2) should be $|x+iy-a|=r$. And for complex numbers, $|z-a|^2\ne(z-a)^2$. And that's where I stopped reading.

Comment: thank you very much, i did not know that, there I saw another proof which is very different-
|z−a|2  =r2      

   (z−a)(z'−a')=r2   

       zz'−az−a'z'+aa'=r2,
and I think it can not be compared with the cartesian equation,

Comment: I don't know what you mean, and you are not helping me by insisting on writing r2 when you could just as easily and far more correctly write $r^2$. Learn MathJax, please, the sooner the better. Also, until you correct the errors I pointed out, I don't intend to look any further into your work.

Comment: See https://studymath.github.io/assets/docs/real_complex_bash.pdf

Answer (score 2):

One of the differences is $|z|^2 \ne z^2$ for most complex numbers $z$. Take $z = i$ as an example: $$z^2 = i^2 = -1 \ne 1 = 1^2 = |z|^2.$$

I think that you misunderstood the concept of an absolute value for complex numbers which led to several mistakes in your proof. [One possible definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) goes as follows: for any complex number $z = x + iy$ $$|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$$ The absolute value of a complex number is also sometimes called its *norm* to highlight the difference from real numbers.

Using this definition the proof becomes simple: first, shift $a$ to $0$ so that we don't have to worry about it, then (for $r \ge 0$ ofc) $$|z| = r \iff \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = r \iff x^2 + y^2 = r^2,$$ which is exactly the equation of a circle in a real plane.

Comment: is there any form of equation of circle in real number, using modulus?

Comment: @ALvees afaik, the modulus is only useful for the equation of a circle in a _complex_ plane. Wikipedia has an [extensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) of circle equations in different coordinates, you can refer to it